# How to Select from table records except some columns

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, datagridview, linq-to-entities

I have a entity database, created from sql database. I need to show record on datagridview, i am using this code.

```
DBEntities db = new DBEntities();
dataGridView1.DataSource = db.Agent.Select(x => new { Name = x.Name, Second_Name = x.Second_Name}).ToList();
```

It's example, real agent table contain around 10 columns, and i need to show all, exept 'id'. If i do same for every 8 columns, become a long and senseless row. How to do it more obliviuous and good.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you don't want to use an anonymous type to specify the fields you want, you can:

1. Live with having the ID in the result set, or
2. Include all of the columns in the `Select` except for the ID, or
3. Use a mapping library, like AutoMapper.

There's no `Select Except` statement in Linq.  However, you can use this extension method to accomplish the same thing:

```
/// <summary>
/// Returns all fields/properties from <paramref name="source"/> except for the field(s)/property(ies) listed in the selector expression.
/// </summary>
public static IQueryable SelectExcept<TSource, TResult>( this IQueryable<TSource> source, Expression<Func<TSource, TResult>> selector )
{
    var newExpression = selector.Body as NewExpression;

    var excludeProperties = newExpression != null
            ? newExpression.Members.Select( m => m.Name )
            : new[] { ( (MemberExpression)selector.Body ).Member.Name };

    var sourceType = typeof( TSource );
    var allowedSelectTypes = new Type[] { typeof( string ), typeof( ValueType ) };
    var sourceProperties = sourceType.GetProperties( BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance ).Where( p => allowedSelectTypes.Any( t => t.IsAssignableFrom( ( (PropertyInfo)p ).PropertyType ) ) ).Select( p => ( (MemberInfo)p ).Name );
    var sourceFields = sourceType.GetFields( BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance ).Where( f => allowedSelectTypes.Any( t => t.IsAssignableFrom( ( (FieldInfo)f ).FieldType ) ) ).Select( f => ( (MemberInfo)f ).Name );

    var selectFields = sourceProperties.Concat( sourceFields ).Where( p => !excludeProperties.Contains( p ) ).ToArray();

    var dynamicSelect = 
            string.Format( "new( {0} )",
                    string.Join( ", ", selectFields ) );

    return selectFields.Count() > 0
        ? source.Select( dynamicSelect )
        : Enumerable.Empty<TSource>().AsQueryable<TSource>();
}
```

**Further Reading**
[Use SelectExcept When You Are Too Lazy to Type](http://terryaney.wordpress.com/2013/02/27/use-selectexcept-when-you-are-too-lazy-to-type/)

Comment: I do not want to be rude, but this is wrong. Through anonymous types you can select only some columns and the Id column can be excluded.

Comment: @OgnyanDimitrov: The OP stated specifically in his question that he did not want to do this.  That's why I did not include it in my answer.

Comment: I said that because (1) we can live without the Id column in the result set and (2) display it properly in the daraGridView (3) keeping the query to the best possible (4) and all this without the jitter of anonymous types (by using AutoMapper or another mapper).

Comment: @OgnyanDimitrov Adding the complexity of an additional library (which very likely uses Reflection to do its work) just to eliminate an ID doesn't seem like a reasonable tradeoff to me.

Comment: You are right :) Not a good tradeoff. But it is widely used and the learning curve is not steep. Another way I think of is that you do not need to add a library. This is an option. You can make the mapping by hand in static method in order not to do visual jitter.

Comment: That is the story :) Upvoting :)

Comment: @RobertHarvey, many thanks for this suggestion, I am trying to use the above method to remove only two fields from 15 fields and getting an error here `return selectFields.Length > 0
                ? source.Select(dynamicSelect)
                : Enumerable.Empty<TSource>().AsQueryable<TSource>();`  the type arguments of the method (method signature) cannot be inferred from usage, try specifying the arguments explicitly

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you use automapper to convert the entity object to a domain object?

```
Mapper.CreateMap<Agent, AgentDto>();
dataGridView1.DataSource = db.Agent.Select(x => Mapper.Map<AgentDto>(x)).ToList();
```

The AgentDto will contain all the fields except 'Id'

Answer (score 0):

This question is answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14339484/1042934) and it is definitely possible. You can cast the selected columns again into enumerable of the original object if the undesired properties are nullable or you can use anonymous.

For example :

1. Full query tested in LINQ Pad agains real table

   from l in Lessons
   select new
   {
       l.Id,
       l.Description,
       l.LanguageId,
       l.CreatedOn
   }

has resulting SQL :

```
SELECT [t0].[Id], [t0].[Description], [t0].[LanguageId], [t0].[CreatedOn]
FROM [Lessons] AS [t0]
```

2. The cut version tested in LINQ Pad with less columns

   from l in Lessons
   select new
   {
       l.CreatedOn
   }

has resulting SQL :

```
SELECT [t0].[CreatedOn]
FROM [Lessons] AS [t0]
```

After all that [you can hide a column in the dataGridView.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383893%28v=vs.90%29.aspx)

If you do not want to write the anonymous object you can use AutoMapper as @
maruthu chandrasekaran suggested.

This way you will be able to server your linq query reduced and map it to your object in one row without the jitter of anonymous object. You can create a DTO object too. Using Entity-EntityDto mappings with AutoMapper is an easy job.