# Entity Framework Except Fields

Tags: entity-framework, select, except, unselect

I want to call all columns but except some fields. For example only base table select not include relationships.

```
 var _person= db.Persons.Select(x => new
            {
                x.id,
                x.Name,
                x.Surname,
                x.Age,
                ....
x.Address.City ..
            }).ToList();
```

I want to `select => var _person= db.Persons.UNSelect(x => x.Address).ToList();`

Unselect or Except or nondisplay ???

Comment: Duplicated of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27205761/how-to-select-from-table-records-except-some-columns

Comment: *only base table select not include relationsships*: just disable lazy loading. If you want to include data like `x.Address.City`: just type it out and make your code self-explanatory. Or consider AutoMapper with flattening.